# javascript identifier lookup

Tags: javascript

i am reading *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*

there is something wierd.

```
var color = "blue";

function getColor() {
    var color = "red";
    return color;
}

getColor();   // "red"
```

the answer is obvious. But following explanation is wierd. "If one of the operands is an object and the other is not, the valueOf() method is called on the object to retrieve a primitive value to compare according to the previous rules."

i just don't get it. It's obvious that what ever happens, it returns the local color.

Comment: The explanation has nothing related to the sample code.

Comment: I can't see a two-operand expression in your code

Comment: <There was a comment, implying that there are two-operand assignment expressions> As per ECMAScript specification, they're 'Variable statements'. Each consists of 'Identifier' and 'Initializer'. 'Initializer' consists of '=' sign and 'Assignment expression', which in this case is a simple string literal.

Comment: @xdazz i thought the same way

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct, it will always return red. The explanation, whilst technically correct appears out of place in this instance. Gee it's hard enough to remember all this stuff without being lead astray.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable or function argument is defined in an inner scope with the same name as a variable/argument outside the scope, that variable will overshadow the other. But once you return to the outer scope, the former variable will still have it's initial value. Nothing is being compared your example. It's simply two assignments and a function declaration.

`var color = ...` means a new variable is being made. If we did *not* have the `var` keyword, when the function was called, the variable `color` in the outer scope would have a changed value. But we are only creating a locally-scope variable, one that will not interfere with the other.

Comment: i know what you mean. but as the author said, (if the **operand** points to color), if one of the color is object while the other not, the valueOf method would be called and.....

Answer (score 0):

**your code is this**

```
var color = "blue";

function getColor() {
    var color = "red";
    return color;
}

getColor();   // "red"
```

**Answer**
color variable will always contain red if you called from function because it is locally declare and define.

but after calling function ,if you want to get the value of color, then its value become blue.